# Having trouble with array

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently trying to program a array based program. We have to make a employee class then a tester main class that holds a array of five user input employee names, salaries, and performance rating. The performance rating is used to determine a supplied raise amount. I have it basically done, but when i run the program, nothing happens even though java virtual machine is running. I have looked up and down for the error, anyone can point out what i am doing wrong?

Employee Class

```
public class Employee
{
  private String employeeName;
  private int salary;
  private int performanceRating;

  public Employee()
  {
    employeeName = "";
    salary = 0;
    performanceRating = 0;
  }   
  public String getEmployeeName()
  {
      return employeeName;
  }
  public int getSalary()
  {
      return salary;
  }
  public int getPerformanceRating()
  {
      return performanceRating;
  }
}
```

And this is the tester main class where the error comes in somewhere

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Employee[] work = new Employee[5];
       Scanner scanString = new Scanner(System.in);
       Scanner scanInt = new Scanner(System.in);


       String employeeName = "";
       double salary = 0;
       double performanceRating = 0;

       String choice = scanString.nextLine();
       while(choice.equals("yes"))
       {
            for(int i = 0; i < 5 ;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("What is the employee's name?");
                employeeName = scanString.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Employee's salary");
                salary = scanInt.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Performance? 1 = excellent, 2 = good, 3 = poor");
                performanceRating = scanInt.nextInt();

                work[i] = new Employee();       


            }
            for(int j = 0; j < 5;  j ++)
                if(work[j].getPerformanceRating() == 1)
                {
                    salary = salary * 0.06;
                    System.out.println("Employee " + employeeName + " salary raised to   " + salary);
            }
            else if(performanceRating == 2)
            {
                salary = salary * 0.04;
                System.out.println("Employee " + employeeName + " salary raised to " + salary);
                }
                else if(performanceRating == 3)
                {
                    salary = salary * 0.015;
                    System.out.println("Employee " + employeeName + " salary raised to " + salary);
                }
                else if(performanceRating < 5)
                {
                    salary = salary;
                    System.out.println("Rating is off scale. No raise for emplyee " + employeeName);
                }
                System.out.println("Enter more employees? type 'yes' if you want to go again");
                choice = scanString.nextLine();
            }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

   }
```

Comment: You never set the fields of a created `Employee`, you're mixing the getter `getPerformanceRating` with the local variable `performanceRating`, you're not really updating their salary (`getSalary` won't change), you're asking to enter more employees while you're still printing their updated salaries...

Answer (score 0):

The program reads from `System.in`. If you don't enter anything, nothing will happen.

Not sure why you have 2 Scanners instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

You have `while(choice.equals("yes"))` except you never prompt the user to make a choice. The program does do stuff (some of which may not all work properly), but you have to give the program input. What you can do is ask the user a question before the line `String choice = scanString.nextLine();`.

As a side note, you could use a `switch` in place of the `if` and `else if`'s and it might be a little easier to read and understand.